# how to stop using vb.net new code editing features in visual studio 2015 like comment within if block or _ for new line

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

We have migrated from VS2012 to VS 2015 recently. All our developers have VS2015 installed on our machines. But our BUILD team is still having VS 2012. As a result of this Newly written VB.Net code is getting errors while compiling on BUILD team server but the same is getting compiled successfully on local machines.

I want to turn off these new code editing features of VS 2015 which allows following things

1. Allows comments in loops: VS2015 allows us to write comment in between multiline IF statement between If and Then please follow below screenshot for details:
   [Difference between VS2015 and VS2012 Code Editors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WoL5.png)
2. One more Issue we came across is in VB.NET we have to continue same statement on next line we use "_" operator. this is not needed from VS 2015 above editors.

These features I want to stop using so that it can get builded successfully on BUILD servers using VS2012 Build script.

Things I have tried are as follows:
1. I have tried to change seetings in Debug-> Options->Debugging -> general->
Checking and Unchecking i. Use the Legacy C# and VB expression evaluators, ii. Use Native Managed Code, iii.Use Managed Compatability Mode

2.I have also tried to change the version of VB.Net Language in .vbproj file as follows:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
     <LangVersion>12</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Both of these approaches failed and in VS 2015 we were able to compile the code successfully on Local.

we want to turn of this Code Editing features of VS 2015 and we shall get compilation errors or errors while writing code itself as in VS2012.
Kindly Help.

Comment: Does your build team have the latest version of the .Net framework installed?  If so, can't they just MSBuild to build the code?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway No they dont have latest version of .Net Framework installed.